# initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, kaa

While configuring kaa -iot platform as a single node using debian package. I was getting following error.

```
himanshu@himpc:~/kaa/deb$ sudo dpkg -i kaa-node-0.10.0.deb
(Reading database ... 239242 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kaa-node-0.10.0.deb ...
Unpacking kaa-node (0.10.0) over (0.10.0) ...
Setting up kaa-node (0.10.0) ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'mongod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
```

I was trying to setup kaa iot on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/614970/vivid-failed-to-connect-to-upstart-connection-refused may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you installed mongodb for ubuntu 14 not 16 that's why it's still trying to use upstart, while ubuntu 16 use systemd as new service framework
Either use ubuntu 14 or reinstall mongodb with right ubuntu target